# Windows Phone Listview Headers

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a list of objects bound to a ListView in Windows Phone 7 and have bound it as follows:

```
<ListBox Height="595" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0" Name="lst_Today"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="lst_Today_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                            
                        <DataTemplate>                                
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                    
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>                                
                        </DataTemplate>                            
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

I get an output that looks like this

Name118:00

Name219:00

Name313:00
.

.

.

.

.

I'd like to add some spacing between the two properties (i.e. name and start time) and potentially add column headers to the list so that the result looks like this:

Name   StartTime

Name1  18:00

Name2  19:00

Name3  13:00
.

.

.

.

Is this possible using a listview or should I be using something else like a Grid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Grid Height="500">

 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


   <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10" />
   <TextBlock Text="Start Time" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Padding="10" />

   <ListBox Height="595" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0" Name="lst_Today"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    .......
   </listBox>


</Grid>
```

Try this one, i think it helps to you...

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is perfectly fine, You just need to set the margin to give some spacing between your items.

10px margin on the 2nd TextBlock

```
<ListBox Height="595" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0" Name="lst_Today"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="lst_Today_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>                            
                        <DataTemplate>                                
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                    
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="{Binding StartTime}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>                                
                        </DataTemplate>                            
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

You could also use a Grid instead of the StackPanel. If you create a column definition, and don't use the column, it will work the same as the Margin would work, but is more explicit.

```
<ListBox Height="595" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,6,0,0" Name="lst_Today"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="441" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionChanged="lst_Today_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding StartTime}"></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

And as far as adding a Header, you could- Add a dummy Item, or just use a regular control above the entire `ListBox`. It depends on whether you want it to scroll with the items or not.

If you want it to scroll, either add a dummy item which is the header, or disable scrolling on the `ListBox`, add the header above the `ListBox`, and wrap them both in a `ScrollViewer`.